# trying to connect my vue.js app to my anchor program deployed on devnet, but can't get past this error

Tags: anchor, javascript

t`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'postV0') at sendTweet (send-tweet.js?74a7:53:1) at async send (VM4954 TweetForm.vue:49:21)`

````
 
    const wallet = useAnchorWallet()
    const connection = new Connection(clusterUrl, commitment)
    const provider = computed(() => new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet.value, { preflightCommitment, commitment }))
    const program = computed(() => new Program(idl, programID, provider.value))

    workspace = {
        wallet,
        connection,
        provider,
        program,
    }
      console.log(workspace);
      console.log("Wallet: " + workspace.wallet.value.publicKey)
      console.log("Programid: " + programID)
   
      console.log("Vault pda: " + vaultPDA);
      console.log("Wallet: " + workspace.wallet.value.publicKey)
      console.log("Content pda: " + contentPDA);

      console.log("cluster: " + clusterUrl)

      try {
        await program.rpc.postV0(content, new anchor.BN(amount), new anchor.BN(threshold), {
            accounts: {
                  content: contentPDA,
                  poster: workspace.wallet.value.publicKey,
                  vault: vaultPDA,
                  systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
              },
              signers: [workspace.wallet.value],
            });
        }
        catch(e){
          const errorLogs = e;
          console.log(errorLogs)
        }```
````

Comment: I dont think program.rpc syntax is used anymore the current syntax for invoking a tx look's something like this program.methods.yourIx(params).accounts({accountList}).rpc()

Comment: Same result with different syntax